# 'Join' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I prepared simple SQLAlchemy with MySQL Python connector, query like below:

```
regions = Table('regions', metadata, autoload = true)
counties = regions.alias('counties')
states = regions.alias('states')

results = regions.select().where(
    and_(
        or_(
            regions.c.type == 3,
            regions.c.type == 4,
            regions.c.type == 5
        ),
        regions.c.name == data['name'],
        counties.c.name == data['county'],
        states.c.name == data['state']
    )
).join(
    counties,
    counties.c.id == regions.c.parent_id
).join(
    states,
    states.c.id == counties.c.parent_id
).execute()
```

The SQL query is prefectly generated, but I can't executed it.
I got error message:

> AttributeError: 'Join' object has no attribute 'execute'

But, when I remove double `.join()` everything is works corectly.

Any solutions?

Comment: Pass the statement to the `execute()` method of a connection object. The implicit execution style you've used is deprecated, and gone in SQLA 2.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `execute()` method, it is simply not existing (as the error says).

The `execute()` method in SQLAlchemy is used to execute raw SQL statements.

Comment: I edited question for adding term: But, when I remove double `.join()` everything is works corectly.